# Joint distribution of discrete (Dirac) and continuous rvs

Tags: probability, measure-theory

so I have a discrete rv $Z \sim \frac{1}{2} \delta_{-1}+ \frac{1}{2} \delta_{1}$ and a continuous one $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Now I've tried to compute its joint distribution function $F^{(Z,X)}$ for $A=Z\cdot X,$ but the Dirac measure sort of puzzles me. I did end up with  a step function for $Z$ (cdf), but yet don't know how to incoperate $F_X$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to find the joint distribution of $X$ and $Z$, it is simply$$f(x,z)={1\over 2\sqrt {2\pi}}e^{-{x^2\over 2}}\left[\delta(z-{1\over 2})+\delta(z+{1\over 2})\right]$$
because of independence.

If you mean to find the PDF of $A=X\cdot Z$, it could be written as $$\Pr\{A<a\}{=\Pr\{XZ<a\}
\\=\Pr\{XZ<a,Z>0\}+\Pr\{XZ<a,Z<0\}
\\=\Pr\{XZ<a|Z>0\}\Pr\{Z> 0\}+\Pr\{XZ<a|Z\le0\}\Pr\{Z\le 0\}
\\={\Pr\{XZ<a|Z=1\}\Pr\{Z> 0\}+\Pr\{XZ<a|Z=-1\}\over 2}
\\={\Pr\{X<a\}+\Pr\{X>-a\}\over 2}
\\={\Pr\{X<a\}}
}$$
which means that $A$ has the same distribution of $X$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try to find the exp. value of A, using f(x,z).